# Getting error Access was denied - ASP .NET. You don't have authorization to view this page.

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am doing a simple new view on a MVC ASP .NET

Here, I am doing the href:

```
$(document).on('click', '.viewFormacion', function () {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    location.href = baseURL + "Farmacia/ModalPopUp/";
});
```

Farmacia is the controller and ModalPopUp is the method.

Inside FarmaciaController I have the method:

```
public ActionResult ModalPopUp(int id, int vid = 0)
{
        return View();
}
```

I created also a new simple View Called ModalPopUp.

When I am going to Farmacia/ModalPopUp/ I received the error.

```
You don't have authorization to view this page.
HTTP ERROR 403
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: not sure if it's related to the 403 (check your permissions on the server / application) but the ModalPopup action method expects two parameters (`id` and (optionally) `vid`, but when you do your `location.href` you don't send either of them. Try `location.href = baseURL + "Farmacia/ModalPopUp/?id=" + id;` to make it include the id in the URL. `id` is required so if you don't send it, you the action method won't work.

Comment: How is the MVC site secured? Are you viewing the site through IIS or something equivalent? If so, what kind of authentication does your site expect?

Comment: @ADyson I tried your solution, makes sense, but still not working.

Now I have this URL: .../Farmacia/ModalPopUp/?id=100

And this message again: You don't have authorization to view this page.
HTTP ERROR 403

Comment: Like I said, I doubt it's directly related to the 403. That's a server-side permissions error. Check if you have any authentication or authorisation rules in place in your application. Do any other action methods have this problem, or just this one only?

Comment: Without knowing any further information, I can only suggest you [search for info about the error message](https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=active&ei=Aa2jW6fwEIjTsAeSkabQAw&q=asp.net+mvc+403+error&oq=asp.net+mvc+403+error&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30k1l2j0i8i7i30k1l2.1682.2687.0.2783.8.8.0.0.0.0.137.729.3j4.7.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..3.5.508...0i13i5i30k1j0i8i13i30k1j35i39k1j0i8i30k1.0.CC-v7ZwDC-M) and see if any of the solutions relate to your situation

Comment: How can I solve? There is some file that I am missing to write to get permissions ?

Comment: Only this one @ADyson

Comment: In a text editor, type in the path you think should work - I often copy and paste from the controller. Paste this into the navbar in the browser and see if it works. I have had issues in the past with my bad spelling catching me out and trying to access non-existent URLs